# How to NOINDEX the layared navigation and forms to avoid being indexed by google

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, forms, google-analytics

Price is one of the attribute filtering, however in Google search result it displays all the parameters. In addition, I could see some content of the "return" form we have in search result. Should I use below code to avoid this indexing? but how goes for forms?

```
    <layout>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</meta></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
   </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

create robots.txt at the root folder of your magento installation and `Disallow: /*?price=*`

you can have many more also like as follows

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

etc

Comment: I guess with your solution, if the pages have links, the value won’t be passed onto other pages because Google won’t access the page. I rather using NOINDEX but have not figured it out